# Windows 8 and Windows server 2012 are throwing an error ".Net Framework 3.5 is not installed"

Tags: c#, installshield

Windows 8 and Windows server 2012 are throwing an error ".Net Framework 3.5 is not installed" when i am trying to install the setup. My setup is created using InstallShield 2011 and all the dll's are built using .Net Framework 4.0 and has no dependency on .Net Framework 3.5. And the prerequisit check in the installer is ".NET Framework 4.0 Full Package".

Answer (score 2):

yes when you install win 8 you have .net 4.0 installed but you don't have .net 3.5 so you have to download and install it. I did the same myself and it is working well :) it is because .net 4.0 does not completely contain .net 3.5, weird but true.

Comment: Yes it weird and i learnt just now that we need to have .Net 3.5 for .net 4.0. Simply .net 4.0 depends upon .net 3.5.http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/12551.aspx

Comment: Actually I get this with a native application with seemingly no references to .net anywhere, just investigating now!...